# Primefaces Jquery Requests So slow

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces, primefaces-datatable

I am getting weird slowness issue with Primefaces. For example i want to change pagination to next page it takes around 20-25 second. Even It doesnt go to database or anywhere . It just take data from backing bean. As you can see below

[image]

Even if I try to update inputtext from datatable row select event which opened inside of dialog . I mean i want to update to inputtext when user select any row in datatable in dialog. Even that takes at least 8-10 seconds to update inputtext field.

[image]

Initiator and paths which primefaces passing by are like
[image]

I couldn't figure out what's wrong.

My xhtml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>Management Dashboard</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>


    <ui:composition template="./templateInternal.xhtml">

        <ui:define name="content">

            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.0.0" type=""></script>


            <style type="">
                .ui-chart {
                    width: 100% !important;
                }

                .ui-panelgrid-content {
                    align-items: center;
                }

                .ui-paginator {
                    display: flex;
                }

                #testt\:onlineUsers {
                    height: 100%;
                }

                #testt\:onlineUsers_content {
                    height: 92%;
                }

                #testt\:depFillTimeLine {
                    height: 100%;
                }

                #testt\:depFillTimeLine_content {
                    height: 94%;
                }

                div.ui-dialog-titlebar.ui-widget-header.ui-helper-clearfix.ui-corner-top.ui-draggable-handle {
                    display: none;
                }

                body .ui-datatable .ui-paginator.ui-paginator-top {
                    display: flex;
                    align-items: center;
                    justify-content: center;
                }

                body .ui-datatable .ui-paginator.ui-paginator-bottom {
                    display: flex;
                    align-items: center;
                    justify-content: center;
                }
            </style>
            <script type="">
                function chartExtender() {
                    var options = {
                        plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
                        options: {
                            plugins: {
                                // Change options for ALL labels of THIS CHART
                                datalabels: {
                                    color: '#36A2EB'
                                },
                                legend: {
                                    display: true,
                                    position: "right",
                                    align: "center",
                                    fullSize: true,
                                    fontFamily: "Allianz-Neo",
                                    textDirection: 'ltr',
                                    labels: {
                                        usePointStyle: true,
                                        fontColor: "#006192",
                                        padding: 23,
                                        font: {
                                            size: 25
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        data: {
                            datasets: [{
                                // Change options only for labels of THIS DATASET
                                datalabels: {
                                    color: '#FFF'
                                }
                            }]
                        },

                    };
                    //merge all options into the main chart options
                    $.extend(true, this.cfg.config, options);
                };

                function onrangechange1() {
                    var first = PF('timelineFirstWdgt');
                    if (first.jq.data("rangeFired")) {
                        first.jq.data("rangeFired", null);
                        return;
                    }
                }

            </script>

            <h1 class="pageHeaders animated fadeIn" style="padding-left: 40px;">Management Dashboard</h1>

            <div id="fullPageContent" class=" animated fadeIn"
                 style="-webkit-animation-delay: 0.6s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */ animation-delay: 0.6s;">

                <h:form id="mainOuterForm">


                    <div class="card">
                        <h:form id="mainInnerForm">


                            <p:panelGrid columns="2" layout="grid" styleClass="showcase-text-align-center">
                                <p:panel id="onlineUsers" header="Online Users">
                                    <p:dataTable var="user" value="#{managementDashboardManagedBean.onlineUsers}"
                                                 paginator="true"
                                                 rows="5" rowKey="#{user.id}" widgetVar="onlineUserWidget"
                                                 paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                                                 rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"
                                                 style="border: ridge;border-color: green;height: 100%">

                                        <f:facet name="header">
                                            Online Users : #{managementDashboardManagedBean.onlineUsers.size()}
                                        </f:facet>

                                        <p:column headerText="Login Name">
                                            <h:outputText value="#{user.user_name}"/>
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column headerText="Login Time">
                                            <h:outputText value="#{user.logIn_date}"/>
                                        </p:column>

                                    </p:dataTable>

                                </p:panel>

                                <p:panel id="projComplStatus" header="Project Complete Status">
                                    <p:dataTable var="project" value="#{managementDashboardManagedBean.projects}"
                                                 rowKey="#{project.id}" widgetVar="projectsWidget"
                                                 selectionMode="single"
                                                 selection="#{managementDashboardManagedBean.selectedProject}"
                                                 paginator="true"
                                                 paginatorPosition="both"
                                                 paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                                                 currentPageReportTemplate="{startRecord}-{endRecord} of {totalRecords} records"
                                                 rowsPerPageTemplate="3,30,50,100,1000" rows="3"
                                                 id="projectTable">

                                        <p:column headerText="Name" sortBy="#{project.name}" filterBy="#{project.name}">
                                            <h:outputText value="#{project.name}"/>
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column headerText="Priority" sortBy="#{project.priority}"
                                                  filterBy="#{project.priority}">
                                            <h:outputText value="#{project.priority}"/>
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column headerText="Create Date" sortBy="#{project.createdDate}"
                                                  filterBy="#{project.createdDate}">
                                            <h:outputText value="#{project.createdDate}"/>
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column headerText="Complete Status">
                                            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{project.status}" itemLabel="Done"/>
                                        </p:column>


                                    </p:dataTable>
                                </p:panel>


                            </p:panelGrid>

                            <p:panelGrid columns="2" layout="grid" styleClass="showcase-text-align-center">

                                <p:panel id="depRecords" header="Department Records">
                                    <p:pieChart model="#{managementDashboardManagedBean.pieModel}" style="width: 20%"/>

                                </p:panel>

                                <p:panel id="depFillTimeLine" header="Department Data Filling Timeline">

                                    <p:tabView>
                                        <p:tab title="Product">
                                            <p class="m-0">
                                                Product
                                            </p>
                                        </p:tab>
                                        <p:tab title="Marketing">
                                            <p class="m-0">
                                                Marketing
                                            </p>
                                        </p:tab>
                                        <p:tab title="SCBA">
                                            <p class="m-0">
                                                SCBA
                                            </p>
                                        </p:tab>
                                        <p:tab title="QA">
                                            <p class="m-0">
                                                QA
                                            </p>
                                        </p:tab>
                                        <p:tab title="Demand Planning">
                                            <p class="m-0">
                                                Demand Planning
                                            </p>
                                        </p:tab>
                                        <p:tab title="Product Development">
                                            <p class="m-0">
                                                Product Development
                                            </p>
                                        </p:tab>
                                        <p:tab title="Bdm">
                                            <p class="m-0">
                                                Bdm
                                            </p>
                                        </p:tab>
                                        <p:tab title="Costing">
                                            <p class="m-0">
                                                Costing
                                            </p>
                                        </p:tab>
                                        <p:tab title="Sourcing Dimension">
                                            <p class="m-0">
                                                Sourcing Dimension
                                            </p>
                                        </p:tab>
                                        <p:tab title="Sourcing Packaging">
                                            <p class="m-0">
                                                Sourcing Packaging
                                            </p>
                                        </p:tab>
                                        <p:tab title="Pricing">
                                            <p class="m-0">
                                                Pricing
                                            </p>
                                        </p:tab>
                                        <p:tab title="Merchandising">
                                            <p class="m-0">
                                                Merchandising
                                            </p>
                                        </p:tab>
                                    </p:tabView>
                                    <p:timeline id="timelineFirst" value="#{managementDashboardManagedBean.modelFirst}"
                                                var="task"
                                                height="250px" widgetVar="timelineFirstWdgt"
                                                start="#{managementDashboardManagedBean.start}"
                                                end="#{managementDashboardManagedBean.end}">
                                        <p:ajax event="rangechange" process="@none"
                                                onstart="onrangechange1(); return false;"/>

                                        <h:panelGroup layout="block" rendered="#{not task.period}"
                                                      style="padding-bottom:5px">
                                            <h:outputText value="#{task.title}"/>
                                        </h:panelGroup>
                                        <p:graphicImage name="#{task.imagePath}" height="50px"/>
                                        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{task.period}" style="padding:8px">
                                            <h:outputText value="#{task.title}"/>
                                        </h:panelGroup>
                                    </p:timeline>
                                </p:panel>


                            </p:panelGrid>

                            <p:panelGrid columns="2" layout="grid" styleClass="showcase-text-align-center">

                                <p:panel id="projSteps" header="Project Steps">

                                    <div class="card">
                                        <h:form id="projStepsForm">
                                            <p:commandButton value="Choose Project" icon="pi pi-home"
                                                             style="display: inline-block !important;"
                                                             onclick="PF('chooseProjectDialog').show()"/>
                                            <p:inputText id="choosenProject"
                                                         style="display: inline-block !important;margin-left: 15px;width: 75%;text-align: center;"
                                                         value="#{managementDashboardManagedBean.selectedProject.name}"
                                                         disabled="true"/>
                                            <p:chronoline value="#{managementDashboardManagedBean.events}" var="event"
                                                          align="alternate" styleClass="customized-chronoline"
                                                          style="margin-top: 10px">

                                                <p:card>
                                                    <f:facet name="title">
                                                        #{event.status}
                                                    </f:facet>
                                                    <f:facet name="subtitle">
                                                        #{event.date}
                                                    </f:facet>

                                                    <p:graphicImage rendered="#{not empty event.image}" width="200"
                                                                    styleClass="shadow-1"
                                                                    value="../../resources/demo/images/product/#{event.image}"
                                                                    alt="#{event.image}"/>
                                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore sed consequuntur error repudiandae numquam deserunt
                                                        quisquam repellat libero asperiores earum nam nobis, culpa ratione quam perferendis esse, cupiditate neque quas!</p>
                                                    <p:commandButton value="Read more" styleClass="ui-button-flat"/>
                                                </p:card>

                                                <f:facet name="marker">
                                            <span class="custom-marker shadow-1"
                                                  style="background-color: #{event.color}"><i
                                                    class="#{event.icon}"/></span>
                                                </f:facet>
                                            </p:chronoline>

                                        </h:form>
                                    </div>

                                </p:panel>
                            </p:panelGrid>


                        </h:form>
                    </div>


                    <p:dialog widgetVar="chooseProjectDialog" closeOnEscape="true" width="1200"
                              height="760" resizable="false" showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode">
                        <h:form id="dlgF">
                            <p:dataTable id="chooseProjectTable" var="project"
                                         value="#{managementDashboardManagedBean.projects}" rowKey="#{project.id}"
                                         selectionMode="single"
                                         selection="#{managementDashboardManagedBean.selectedProject}"
                                         paginator="true"
                                         paginatorPosition="both"
                                         paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                                         currentPageReportTemplate="{startRecord}-{endRecord} of {totalRecords} records"
                                         rowsPerPageTemplate="15,30,50,100,1000" rows="15">
                                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" onstart="PF('chooseProjectDialog').hide();" update=":mainOuterForm:mainInnerForm:projStepsForm:choosenProject"
                                       />
                                <p:column headerText="Name" sortBy="#{project.name}" filterBy="#{project.name}">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{project.name}"/>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="Priority" sortBy="#{project.priority}"
                                          filterBy="#{project.priority}">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{project.priority}"/>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="Create Date" sortBy="#{project.createdDate}"
                                          filterBy="#{project.createdDate}">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{project.createdDate}"/>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="Complete Status">
                                    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{project.status}" itemLabel="Done"/>
                                </p:column>
                            </p:dataTable>
                        </h:form>
                    </p:dialog>

                </h:form>

            </div>

        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

JSF: 2.2.1, PrimeFaces: 12.0.0, PrimeFaces Extensions: 12.0.5

Comment: I found the issue. The form shouldn't exist if we are using panelgrids. When i deleted form tag all requests made under 1 sec :D